# Include mapGetters from vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How do we include the `mapGetters` helper if we use vuex with a tag

```
<script src="/vuex.min.js"></script
```

and not with the import method

Answer (score 2):

```js
const mapGetters = Vuex.mapGetters

console.log(mapGetters)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.1/dist/vuex.js"></script>
```